# Flexicious HTML DataGrid hide row based on column value

Tags: html, datagrid, treegrid, flexicious

I have recently started working with HTML tree grid and was able to figure out how to hide different column based on visibility. My question to the developer is there a way by which I can hide a row in grid based on specific column value?

For example if there is a column called quantity if the value in this column is 0 then i need to hide all the rows in which quantity is 0

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways - you can use an external filter function: Here is an example : http://www.htmltreegrid.com/demo/prod_jq_treegrid.html?example=External%20Filter